# Does seawater foam more when its warm? And if so, why

Tags: heat, chemical-biology

I work at an oil rig out in the sea.

We are pumping seawater into the rig, and back out again after it has gone through the system.

Its really warm outside now, and when we are pumping seawater into the ocean it foams much more than usual.
The technical department think something is wrong with either the equipment we use, or an imbalance in the chemicals.
The old veterans onboard says this always happens when its warm and its nothing to worry about.

Can anyone elaborate?

Comment: Pure water can’t foam, but seawater is far from pure and maybe warm seawater has more plankton and other organic debris in it that would facilitate foaming. Just my two cents.

Comment: Pumping seawater **into** the ocean? Then it's not exactly seawater any more, just some waste?

Comment: As @EdV states, check the coastal water report for algae blooms. The foam is likely from organic byproducts. If you're near the estuary of a river, it could also be due to organics released from industry, agriculture and other sources after heavy rains, more likely in warmer weather.

Comment: How long does the water reside on the rig before it gets pumped out. Is it kept at room temperature or used for cooling purposes? Are you pumping it in from the surface (where the temperature would vary more) or from deeper down (where the temperature would vary less)?